# Magento : how to use serialized data to filter while making Collection?

Tags: magento

I am using Multi-select on frontend for Categories. When form Submitted then I save Categories in Serialized format which converts the Categories array into String.

like "**serialize($_Params['categories'])**".

When I am trying to create Collection after making data **unserialized** then it not showing the purposeful result.

Collection what I am trying to create -

```
/* Store Collection */
$_Params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

if($_Params['category']):
    $_Collection = $this->getStoreCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('approval_status', array('eq' => 'approved'))
        ->addFieldToFilter(unserialize('categories'), array(
        'in' => $_Params['category'],
        ))
        ->getData();
```

How can I make it purposeful.

Please Help!

-
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be unserialize('categories') which is not a variable. You also mention that $_Params['category'] was a serialize value, so this is what I think your trying to accomplish

```
/* Store Collection */
$_Params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

if($_Params['category']){
    $_Collection = $this->getStoreCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('approval_status', array('eq' => 'approved'))
        ->addFieldToFilter('categories', array(
        'in' => unserialize($_Params['category']),
    ))
    ->getData();
}
```